# 'mat-toolbar' is not a known element

Tags: html, angular, typescript, toolbar, mat

I used in app.component.html :

```
<mat-toolbar>
  Responsive side navigation
</mat-toolbar>
```

and I define MatToolbarModule in app.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing/app-routing.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatToolbarModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatDividerModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I obtain this error when I execute ng build command:

```
Error: src/app/app.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

please, how to correct this error

Comment: if you are using VSCode, sometimes you need to reset the Angular Language Service. Go to Command Palette, search for Angular, and reset the Language service.

Comment: I reset the Language service but i have the same error

Comment: The code you are showing looks alright, you are indeed importing the correct module. Did you try running `npm install` ? are other material components giving you the same issue?

Comment: I try building after npm install but I haven't any changes the same error is occured.         Yes also other material components giving me the same issue

Comment: Can you show youre package.json?

Comment: This is the content pf package.json file :

Comment: {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "SEE-ONE-MANUFACTURING": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },

Comment: "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/SEE-ONE-MANUFACTURING",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],

Comment: "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],

Comment: "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },

Comment: "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "SEE-ONE-MANUFACTURING:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "SEE-ONE-MANUFACTURING:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },

Comment: "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "SEE-ONE-MANUFACTURING:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",

Comment: "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },

Comment: That was your angular.json file. Do you have something similar->"@angular/material": "^13.3.8", in your package.json?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you shared (before any update) your set up is sufficient to make it working. In case you are on VSCode closing and opening the IDE would be sufficient sometimes to get ride of this kind of compilation errors.
[Here is a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w9ckf8?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts) compatible with your code above works fine.

Comment: It works correctly in a stackblitz, but in my machine it dosent work when closing and opening